# Javascript li list from array with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make `li` elements with properties like below but it doesn't work at all. Could you help me with what is wrong?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, "mm", "b", "c", "mm", "y", "mm"];
var list = document.getElementById("list");

function addText(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++); {
        var text = array[i];
        if (array[i] == "mm") {
            var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
            listItem.innerHTML = text;
            list.appendChild(listItem);
        }     
    }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: could you post all the rest of code to see when you're calling the addTect function and see if the list will be null or not ??

Comment: Why are you checking for `i <= array.length` in your loop?

Comment: You could easily track down problems like this by simply stepping through your code in a debugger. Do you know how to do that? Even if you don't, even adding a `console.log` inside the loop would have let you figure out what was going on. These are basic debugging techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon at the end of the for loop is the problem.

`for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++); // <-- remove this`

The semicolon makes the loop do nothing for array.length + 1 times instead of looping through the code in between the braces. You also want to change the `<=` to `<` so that you don't exceed the array boundary. Arrays are zero based, so your array of 9 items have indices from 0-8. You can also just compare `text` instead since you're copying it to a variable (not sure what was your intent since you can just get rid of the temporary outright).

Also, since you're just adding text, use `textContent` over `innerHTML`

Demo:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, "mm", "b", "c", "mm", "y", "mm"];
var list = document.getElementById("list");

function addText(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var text = array[i];
    if (text == "mm") {
      var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
      listItem.textContent = text;
      list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  }
}

addText(array);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Good catch. Sounds very much like a comment and typo CV. You failed to catch the `<=` problem though. As long as you're fixing up his code, why not fix the duplicate reference to `array[i]`, and change `innerHTML` to `textContent`?

Comment: @torazaburo Caught the `<=` earlier. Tweaked the rest per your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I have a question and sorry if it's stupid, i'm just starting with this.

Why the <= is bad and should be <? I want my function to check all the elements in the array.

Second question is why textContent not innerHTML?

Comment: @MarcinMisiak Good questions. You want `<` because arrays end at length - 1 since they're 0-indexed. You have nine items, but the valid indices are 0-8. Index 9 is invalid in this case so you want to loop from index 0-8, and end when i = 9, hence `<`; `<=` will end at 10, but the code will bomb trying to access index 9. textContent is preferred when you're only writing text inside an element as it is faster due to not having to parse any HTML. If you have HTML in your string, then innerHTML would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two reasons why your code might not work.

### First:

your **for** loop is not doing much other than incrementing var i. You should remove the semicolon after the for loop. Change it to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
```

### Second:

When are you calling your javascript? If you're running **document.getElementById** before you define the element with id "list" then **document.getElementById("list")** will return **undefined**.

One solution is to define the script at the end of your body, such as:

```
  <body>
      <ul id="list">
      </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var array = [1, 2, 3, "mm", "b", "c", "mm", "y", "mm"];
            function addText(array) {
                var list = document.getElementById("list");
                for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
                    var text = array[i];

                    if (array[i] == "mm") {
                        var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
                        listItem.innerHTML = text;
                        list.appendChild(listItem);
                    }     
                }
            };
            window.onload = function(){ addText(array) };
        </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Your `window.onload` is incorrect here.  `addText()` doesn't return a function.  You probably want `window.onload = function(){ addText(array); };`

Comment: You're absolutely right, @RocketHazmat. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, "mm", "b", "c", "mm", "y", "mm"];
var list = document.getElementById("list");

function addText(array) {
  
  array.map(function(element) {
    if(element === 'm'){
      var listItem = document.createElement('LI');
      listItem.textContent = element;
      list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  });
}

addText(array);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the type of list element. It should be a "ul" element for that to achieve what you need.

Comment: Well, this was not the problem.